# Problem with Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to prove that

> If $E$ is a Vector Space, $F,G$ are subspaces of $E$ and if $a+F\subseteq G$, for  some $a \in E$, then $F \subseteq G$.

I tried to prove that $a+F$ is subspace of $E$ but I think that is false. 
Here my attempt:

Suppose that $x\in F$, then $x+a\in a+F$, note that  $a+F$ is subspace (In this part I think that is wrong) then $x+a+(-a)\in a+F$ but $a+F\subseteq G$ thus $x+a+(-a)=x\in G$

Comment: I edited your question slightly to make it a little clearer. Please feel free to revise my edit if you feel it's made your question worse.

Comment: Thanks. That's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a + F \subset G$, and $F$ is a subspace (and thus must contain $0$), $a \in G$. Let $x \in F$. We then have that $$x = a + (x-a) = (a+x) -a \in G,$$ since $a+x\in G$ and $-a \in G$.

Comment: Thanks. You are right.